# REST compatibility over TCPIP

Tags: wcf, http, rest, tcp

I am writing WCF services uses *REST Messaging protocol*.
 Am I correct by saying my WCF service is compatible with TCP/IP transport as well? (HTTP is by default anyways)

Comment: Define "compatible with TCP/IP". HTTP usually _runs on top of_ TCP/IP, if that is what you mean. TCP just ensures your packets are received in order and IP means you can send packets further than your local network. These protocols don't care what data they carry. Perhaps you mean to ask a different question? Or are you writing a document for marketing / management?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, I have read one article somewhere says REST build on top of HTTP and I had thought it might loose transport flexibility different channels like TCP/IP and thereby question raise.  Can you please comment on this link as well..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224803/financial-wcf-service-to-use-soap-or-rest

Comment: _"it might loose transport flexibility different channels like TCP/IP and thereby question raise"_ - I really don't know where you're getting. Can you explain what you want to do and what you are afraid of when using REST?

Comment: I am new to WCF world and here are my actual questions on REST. If I use REST, 1. how can I authenticate request 2. I had written a sample WCF service uses Self tracking Entities/SOAP/HTTP.. However when I had gone through many articles understand Microsoft no more supporting STE and preferred to use OData/REST for WCF services.  Before I proceed with development on same I just need to ensure my Service is more generic as my service will get different types of customer in future.. Please comment..

Comment: Each of those questions can be (and already is) answered separately, try to use the search: [Authenticating WCF Rest webservices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688449/), [Is it recommended to use Self Tracking Entities with WCF services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642390/) and [Different WCF Bindings, their differences and compatibility with other platforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849920/). So that has little to do with TCP/IP compatibility. Mind if I vote to close this question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, REST isn't a protocol, it's an architectural style employed over the HTTP protocol. With that in mind, it's dependent on the HTTP Application layer in the OSI stack, so in essence, any Network layer (i.e TCP/IP) that has an implementation of HTTP above can be used for interfacing in a RESTful manner.

Comment: Thanks you. I have just gone through another link which was resolved many of my queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service